# Recursive function to loop over nth nesting depth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion

## Data I'm working with:

*(I have this in XML format)*

```html
<root>

    <!-- level 1 nesting -->
    <main name="A" category="group">
        <sub name="A.1"></sub>
    </main>

    <!-- level 1 nesting -->
    <main name="B" category="group">
        <sub name="B.1"></sub>
    </main>

    <!-- level 1 nesting -->
    <main name="C" category="group">
        <sub name="C.1"></sub>
    </main>

    <!-- level 1 nesting -->
    <main name="D" category="group">
        <sub name="D.1"></sub>
    </main>

    <!-- level 2 nesting -->
    <main name="E" category="group">
        <sub name="E.1" category="group">
            <sub name="E.1.1"></sub>
        </sub>
    </main>

    <!-- level n nesting - this is what I need help with -->
    <main name="E" category="group">
        [...]
    </main>

</root>
```

## Desired outcome

- I want to print the above out in ULs and LIs according to their relationships shown above to produce a tree-view.
- The nesting depths of the data I'm working with vary (e.g could be a single item or it could be  100 nesting depth - we don't know)
- I need to write a solution that functionally caters for any level of nesting depth
- Either tag (`main` or `sub`) with a `category` attribute value of `"group"` means it has children
- The first level tag is always a `main`, the rest will be `sub` regardless of nesting depth

## What I'm currently trying

```rb
def recursiveLoop(group)
    str = ""
    group.each { |g|

        str +=  "<ul>"
        str +=  "<li>#{g.attribute("name")}"

        if g.attribute("category").to_s == "group"
            recursiveLoop(g.css("sub"))
        else
            str += "</li></ul>"
        end
    }
    return str
end
```

## Problem with my solution

After calling itself, the current iteration terminates (as expected) and goes one level deeper. However, I now can't close the `<li>` nor the `<ul>` tags as I no longer know where they started.

**Edit for CamiloVA**
[image: Pic]

Comment: just move the closing `li` and `ul` out of the `else` block; if every iteration of the block opens and closes one `ul` and one `li` it doesn't matter what goes inside of those, even if something opens (then closes) another `ul` and `li`. Essentially you end up with `"<ul><li>#{name}#{recursive_loop(...)}</li></ul>"` and then eventually something returns `"<ul><li>#{name}</li></ul>"` which is valid to put in where the `recursive_loop(...)` is in the first one leaving you with `"<ul><li>#{name}<ul><li>#{name from recurse}</li></ul></li></ul>"`

Comment: Even if recursive_loop returns multiple `"<ul><li>#{name}</li></ul><ul><li>#{name}</li></ul>"` that's still valid to stick into another `li`: `"<ul><li>#{name}<ul><li>#{name from recurse}</li></ul><ul><li>#{name from recurse iteration 2}</li></ul></li></ul>"` so each iteration of `each` should open and close it's own set of elements

Answer (score 3):

This works

```rb
def recursiveLoop(group)
    str = ""
    group.each { |g|

        str +=  "<li>#{g.attribute("name")}"

        if g.attribute("category").to_s == "group"
            str += "<ul>"
            str += recursiveLoop(g.css("> sub"))
            str += "</ul>"
        end
        str += "</li>"
    }
    return str
end
```

Two things, though:

1. Have a main `<ul>` and `</ul>` tag wrapped around the result of `recursiveLoop` in the markup. Something like this:

```
<%= sanitize "<ul>" + recursiveLoop(@groups) + "</ul>" %>
```

This is only to provide a root node without getting tangled in the other objects being looped over.

2. Be sure to specify `> sub` in the css selector of the XML variable `g` (forgot to mention I'm using [Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/)) to restrict all sub items to their **immediate** parents.

Answer (score 1):

As @simplelime says, you can put the `close tag` after the `if block`, and the return value of function should be concatenated to the same initial `str`, so you will get all the recursive childs inside each main node; and at end of execution it will return the big resulting string.

```
def recursiveLoop(group)
    str = ""
    group.each { |g|

        str +=  "<ul>"
        str +=  "<li>#{g.attribute("name")}"

        if g.attribute("category").to_s == "group"
            str += recursiveLoop(g.css("sub"))
        end
        str += "</li></ul>"
    }
    return str
end
```

Comment: The problem with this is line 9 of this code. The `sub` will count for each nesting depth. Hard to explain but if you go in 3 levels, they'll all count on the parent loop and you'll get duplicate outputs. Added a picture